# Invalid conversion error when overloading ostream& operator<<

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Here is the prototype of my class Rational

```
#ifndef RATIONAL_H
#define RATIONAL_H

//forward declaration
class ostream;

class Rational
{
  int numerator,denominator;
  public:
  // the various constructors
  Rational();
  Rational(int);
  Rational(int,int);

  //member functions
  int get_numerator()const{return numerator;}
  int get_denominator()const{return denominator;}

  // overloaded operators
  // relational operators
  bool operator==(const Rational&)const;
  bool operator<(const Rational&)const;
  bool operator<=(const Rational&)const;
  bool operator>(const Rational&)const;
  bool operator>=(const Rational&)const;

  //arithmetic operators
  Rational operator+(const Rational&)const;
  Rational operator-(const Rational&)const;
  Rational operator*(const Rational&)const;
  Rational operator/(const Rational&)const;

  //output operator
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Rational&);
};
#endif //RATIONAL_H
```

And this is the implementation of the overloaded output operator<< in rational.cpp

```
// friend output operator
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Rational& r)
{
  os<<r.get_numerator()<<"/"<<r.get_denominator();
}
```

When I try to compile I get the following error

```
g++ -c rational.cpp
rational.cpp: In function ‘ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Rational&)’:
rational.cpp:81:26: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
rational.cpp:7:1: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘Rational::Rational(int)’ [-fpermissive]
```

I wanted to be able to display the rational number as numerator/denominator when it is passed to the << operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first issue is that you try to forward declare `ostream` as a class. Assuming that you mean to use `std::ostream`, you can't do that, its not legal.

For one, it's a `typedef` for a template specialization, not a class itself.

Second, because you don't `#include <ostream>` you don't have a definition for any of the standard `<<` overloads for `ostream` so when you try to `<<` a string literal, the compiler trys to convert the string literal to a `Rational` type as that is the only type that has a `<<` overload visible.

Simply, you need to `#include <ostream>` and qualify `ostream` with `std::` where you use it.

A third point is that your overload of `operator<<` needs to return something. You should either append a `return os;` statement or simply `return` the whole streaming expression.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I though it was more efficient to use forward declarations than to include the class at compile time. But that stands corrected now.

Comment: Also the friend function seems to work fine even if i don't return anything, is this because cout is passed as a reference?

Comment: @nikhil: If it works, it's because you are getting lucky. You should explicitly return something to avoid _undefined behavior_.

Comment: It should be pointed out that there is also the standard <iosfwd> header, which includes valid forward declarations for the classes in <isotream>. Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Although I am not sure why you get such error message, I do found an error: you should add:

```
return os;
```

in your friend function.